# Constructing array of term reference labels in php template?

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm currently trying to set up a simple LMS and have already defined a content type `course` that contains a *term reference field* `accesstags`, which I would like to use for defining view permissions. I.e. the field `accesstags` will contain multiple terms that will be linked to roles that should have access to the node in question.

To make a long story short: I have created a custom module that contains the function `hook_entity_view_mode_alter` and I would like to check, whether the term reference field `accesstags` contains the term *"subscription"*:

```
function hook_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $context) {
  ...
  if (in_array('subscription', ?????)) {
    ... allow access ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, I'm not sure what to put at the spot that I marked with "?????". I know that I can construct the array of referenced terms by using `$entity->get('field_accesstags')->referencedEntities()`... but this array then contains the whole structure, whereas I only need the array of labels.

Is there an easy way for getting this array? Maybe even a built-in function?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this array of terms is a good starting point. You'll find the label in `$term->getName()` when iterating the array, for example with `array_filter()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the help that I needed. I ended up using `array_map()` in combination with a small helper function that called `getName()` on the elements of the array built with `referencedEntities()`. Much appreciated. (Would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?)

Comment: You can put the final code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @4k4's suggestion to post the final code as an answer myself... here's the code that I'm now using and that seems to work well...

First of all, I defined a simple helper function:

```
function getTermName($term) {
  return($term->getName());
}
```

This allowed me to extend my code (see my original question above):

```
function hook_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $context) {
  ...
  $accesstags = array_map("getTermName", $entity->get('field_accesstags')->referencedEntities());
  if (in_array('subscription', $accesstags)) {
    ... allow access ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm still wondering, if there is a simpler way (without having to iterate over the array of terms), but for now the solution works well. Thanks again for your help, @4k4.